# Common parameters for SQLDATASOURCE in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sqldatasource

The Insert and Update parameters are SAME for my Sqldatasource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" 
             <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="startdt" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="detail" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="startdt" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="detail" Type="String" />                    
                </UpdateParameters>
```

In code behind I have to write depending on Insert or Update:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Title"].DefaultValue = "Title"

SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Title"].DefaultValue = "Title"
```

There is lot of same stuff that gets repeated. I was wondering if there is a way to eliminate the same repetitive lines in aspx (same parameters)  and in code behind. This would be huge time saver and also help reduce errors.

Comment: Well if you're trying to clean up this code....getting rid of the SqlDataSource entirely would be a great start. SqlDataSource doesn't allow for proper separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [InsertParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insertparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) and [UpdateParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) are parameters of the [ParameterCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

So you could have a helper function that will set all the common parameters. Based on the code snippet in your question, the helper function can be:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public void SetCommonParameters(ParameterCollection params)
{
    params["Title"].DefaultValue = "Title";
    // add all common parameters
}
```

When you do an insert you call:

```
SetCommonParameters(SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters);
```

When you do an update you call:

```
SetCommonParameters(SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters);
```

Comment: This looks like very promising! Thanks